# HTML WARN: The page displayed insecure content

Tags: adobe

HTML WARN: The page at https:// displayed insecure content from http:// we have also used these cross domain policy but cross domain policy does not work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide from-scratch coding service here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.

Comment: This problem caused because you are using SSL. You getting content from insecured (No SSL) web URLS. Every URL without `https` in it would be called `insecure`. Sometimes you can ignore this, but it can be a problem getting content from not-SSL websites.